# Who is this mysterious prisoner?

Tags: riddle

> I am a prisoner in my own home,
>   Armed people are after me,
>   I can't escape this attention,
>   I can't side with anybody.

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> Bull's Eye

Prison

> since he is always at the center and in the circle

Armed people are after me

> Armed people always aim for bull's eye

I can't escape this attention

> bull's eye is the the center of attention since people always aim for it and at the center

I can't side with anybody

> he is always at the center, can't go left or right.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer, though the word I was looking for was the other word you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Who is this mysterious prisoner?

I think it is

> money

Its prison is

> safe or bank

Comment: It is not. Try focusing

Comment: Can you explain why you think that? Answers without explanation are deleted.